# Javascript Calendar Component with Custom Slots

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Do you know of a component or a possibility of how to customize the FullCalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/) to support custom slots?  What I mean by custom slots is that for example, I would like that for each day, rather than having 8am, 9am, 10am, etc., I would have only 3 slots, "Breakfast", "Lunch" and "Dinner".  Events can then be placed only in these 'slots'.  The same functionality would then apply, i.e. the ability to view them by month, week, day, list etc.

Is that possible with Full Calendar or is there anything else which supports the above functionality?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The closest you can get to this would be `Background Events`, more specifically, the `Inverse Background Events`. They can be used to limit where events can be placed to specific times of the day.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  It is a possible option but was more looking at something in which it would limit the slots entirely.   Maybe anybody is aware of another component which serves this purpose?

Comment: FWIW, I'm attempting to do a similar thing with Vue Bootstrap4 Calendar at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785719/add-and-access-slots-in-component-chain-three-components-away